# debugging of driver on separate computer after connecting two computers

Tags: windows, debugging, driver, kmdf, wdf

I am about to start a project that requires debugging of program on separate computer. basically I am writing a file system filter driver. and it's on windows. For that, the debugging of driver has to be on separate system.

I need to know how I can connect two computers so I can run the driver on one system (windows 7) and debug it in visual studio IDE on different system (windows 8.1)

**UPDATE:** on msdn following article is given https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx

It does show creating driver but not specified how to connect two computers, that's my question. how I can do remote debugging in VS and how to do the setup for connecting two computers

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/debugging-a-driver.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are various debugging options available for kernel mode debugging on two separate computers. You can debug via USB cable, network cable and serial cable. I used to do debugging via serial cable and it works normally. Check link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439378(v=vs.85).aspx). You can setup debug environment based on options available at your end. Just make sure that you need to enable debugging in target computer(computer being debugged) and setup WinDbg on host computer(computer which run debugger). Above link provide much information for debugging.